# Dynamic memory array / program crashing

Tags: c++

my program is using dynamic memory arrays and has functions enqueue (add at beginning and shift right) and dequeue (remove last) Show array etc. The code seems fine to me. But there is a problem when you run the program it crashes like 5 out of 10 times. I suppose it is because of wrong new / delete usage. Can someone please tell my why the program is crashing? And how to fix it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Queue
{
public:

    Queue(int size);
    int add_value(T);
    void show_array();
    void enqueue(T);
    T dequeue();

private:

    T *temp;
    T *data;
    int size;
    int index;
};
template<class T>
Queue<T>::Queue(int s)
{
    data = new T[s];
    if (data == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Not enough memory, program ends." << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    size = s;
    index = 0;
}
template<class T>
void Queue<T>::show_array()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
        cout << data[i] << ' ';

    cout << endl;
}
template<class T>
int Queue<T>::add_value(T value)
{
    if (index == size)
    return(1);
    else
    {
      data[index] = value;
      index++;
      return(0);
    }
}
template <class T>
void Queue<T>::enqueue(T X)
{
    for(int i = size; i > 0; i--)
    {
       data[i] = data[i-1];
    }
    data[0] = X;
}
template <class T>
T Queue<T>::dequeue()
{
    size -= 1;
    index -= 1;
    temp = new T[size];
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
        temp[i] = data[i];

    delete[] data;

    data = new T[size];
    data = temp;

    return * data;
}
int main()
{
    Queue<double>numbers(10);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      numbers.add_value(i);

    cout << "Array:" << endl;
    numbers.show_array();
    numbers.enqueue(9.2);
    numbers.enqueue(9.1);
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Array after enqueue:" << endl;
    numbers.show_array();
    cout << "Array after dequeue:" << endl;
    numbers.dequeue();
    numbers.dequeue();
    numbers.show_array();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: did you try to use a debugger? where does it crash? how does it crash?

Comment: The code in dequeue (the only one I read) is terrible. For one thing, if you do `data = new T[size]; data = temp;`, whatever was created with `new T[size];` is lost forever in the deep ocean of memory leaks.

Comment: u run it works, then u run it again u get the windows error program stopped working, u run it again it works then it does not

Comment: data = temp is made on purpose

Comment: Then you are throwing on purpose whatever you allocated with `new T[size];` to the deep ocean of memory leaks.

Comment: `if (data == NULL)` makes only sence with [std::nothrow](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/nothrow/).

Comment: `data = temp;` is ok but without `data = new T[size];` before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have several errors in your code.

First, this is a terribly inefficient method for implementing a queue since each insert will involve copying every element that is currently in the queue.

Second, you access elements out of bounds:

```
for(int i = size; i > 0; i--)
{
   data[i] = data[i-1];
}
```

Since your array is allocated as `data = new T[size]`, accessing `data[size]` is attempting to access 1 element passed the end of the array.  That is UB.

Third, you have a memory leak:

```
T Queue<T>::dequeue()
{
    size -= 1;
    index -= 1;
    temp = new T[size];
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
        temp[i] = data[i];

    delete[] data;

    data = new T[size]; // leaked!
    data = temp;

    return * data;
}
```

It should just be `data = temp`.

Comment: @itwasntpete It was rejected by 4 other people before I even had a chance to look at it.

Answer (score 1):

You have a memory corruption in `enqueue`:

Here is how you should write the for loop:

```
for (int i = size - 1; i > 1; i--)
```

instead of

```
for (int i = size; i > 0; i--)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, can you please explain why the memory corruption happened?

Comment: @Juris Kušta if i == 0 then data[i-1] points outside of the allocated space, also if i == size then temp[i] points outside of allocated space